# How to output the values of a query depending on the value of row?

Tags: coldfusion

If I have a query result like this

```
type_name | count
-----------------
test1     | 5
test2     | 4
test4     | 7
```

How to output the count base on the value of the column `type_name`?

From the table the row value 'test3' doesn't exist, but it doesn't mean it wont exist later after a refresh.

With the below code I will only get the value but looping 3 times since test3 value doesn't exist.

```
<cfoutput name="query">
    <table>
        <tr><td><cfif query.type_name eq 'test1'>#query.count#</cfif></td></tr>
        <tr><td><cfif query.type_name eq 'test2'>#query.count#</cfif></td></tr>
        <tr><td><cfif query.type_name eq 'test3'>#query.count#</cfif></td></tr>
        <tr><td><cfif query.type_name eq 'test4'>#query.count#</cfif></td></tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset testResults = [0,0,0,0]>

<cfloop query="query">
    <cfset testResults[right(query.type_name, 1)] = query.count>
</cfloop>

<table>
<cfloop array="#testResults#" index="count">
  <td>#count#</td>
</cfloop>
</table>
```

You should see

5

4

0

7

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more dynamic approach, you can transform your full query result (all columns) to an array of structs:

```
<!---

    <!--- test data --->
    <cfset query = queryNew("type_name,count", "VARCHAR,INTEGER")>
    <cfset queryAddRow(query, 3)>
    <cfset querySetCell(query, "type_name", "test1", 1)>
    <cfset querySetCell(query, "count", "5", 1)>
    <cfset querySetCell(query, "type_name", "test2", 2)>
    <cfset querySetCell(query, "count", "4", 2)>
    <cfset querySetCell(query, "type_name", "test4", 3)>
    <cfset querySetCell(query, "count", "7", 3)>

--->

<!--- number of tests to list --->
<cfset expectedNumberOfRows = 4>

<!--- remember all columns while transforming query to array of structs --->
<cfset queryColumns = listToArray(query.columnList)>

<!--- initialize array of structs --->
<cfset testResults = arrayNew(1)>
<cfloop from="1" to="#expectedNumberOfRows#" index="i">

    <cfset blankResult = structNew()>

    <!--- initialize all columns for each row --->
    <cfloop array="#queryColumns#" index="columnName">
        <cfset blankResult[columnName] = "">
    </cfloop>

    <!--- default values for specific columns --->
    <cfset blankResult["type_name"] = "test#i#">
    <cfset blankResult["count"]     = "0">

    <cfset testResults.add(blankResult)>
</cfloop>

<!--- transfer cell values from each query row to array of structs --->
<cfset queryRowIndex = 1>
<cfloop query="query">

    <!--- extract possible row index --->
    <cfset testNumber = trim( reReplace(query.type_name, "[^0-9]*([0-9]+)$", "\1") )>

    <!--- transfer cells --->
    <cfif reFind("^[0-9]+$", testNumber)>
        <cfloop array="#queryColumns#" index="columnName">
             <cfset testResults[int(testNumber)][columnName] = query[columnName][queryRowIndex]>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>

    <cfset queryRowIndex++>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>

    <table>
        <cfloop array="#testResults#" index="testResult">
            <tr>
                <td>#testResult.type_name#</td>
                <td>#testResult.count#</td>
                <!--- add additional columns if desired --->
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
    </table>

</cfoutput>
```